# In Powershell how can i use a variable to remove a group from a folders permissions

Tags: powershell

I'm currently doing my pieces trying to get something to work.
I am trying to do the following;
1. Get the existing groups with permissions to a folder (based on a wildcard)
2. Remove those groups from the folder

My script is below;

```
$currentgroups = (get-acl $folderpath).access | where-object -property identityreference -like '*FS1*' | ft identityreference 
$objACL = Get-ACL $folderpath
foreach ($group in $currentgroups){
$accessremoval = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($group, 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessremoval)
set-acl $folderpath $objACL
}
```

$currentgroups works just lovely and if I enter that it returns a list of two groups (in that instance).

Where I'm falling down is on the foreach loop and specifically get the $objacl.removaccessruleAll($accessremoval) bit to work as it returns the following;

Exception calling "RemoveAccessRuleAll" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

If I type the group name in $accessremoval e.g.

```
$accessremoval = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @('FS1-Engineering (RO)', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
```

It works just fine... what am I doing wrong?
I've tried putting $Group in ''s and "" but no luck so far.

thanks in advance.

Paul.

Comment: Remove the `| ft identityreference`.

Comment: Have a look at the NTFSSecurity module in PSGallery - it helps a lot with things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... seems that the ft does something strange... anyhow removing that and then referencing .identityreference in the foreach e.g. foreach($group in $currentgroups.identityreference) did the trick.

all the best.

Paul.

Comment: You should only format when you need the output, not when you're going to use the object. If you need it ordered, use Sort-Object